# How to prevent "remember me" cookie spamming?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have made a remember-me cookie system for my website (pure php). It works like this:

1. User logs in
2. A random token (user id + random sha256 hash) is generated and saved in a cookie for one month
3. The token is also stored in the database (mysql), together with its expiry date (1 month)
4. When user visits my site and has the cookie, I compare it's value with the one in database. If they match, I generate a new token for this cookie to prevent coookie-stealing

This allows users to be logged in from many devices simultaneously, but I ran into a (possible) problem.
When using for example incognito mode, each time you view the website it asks you to login again (because there aren't any cookies obviously). This way, I can login hundreds of times and generate hundreds of tokens that will never be used again, but will take up space in my database and won't be deleted until their expiry date. How could I protect myself against that?

Comment: What you can also do is insert a username and ip within the table that update that record if username and ip is the same.. note that this only works indeed if the device has a static ip

Comment: I already have a event to delete expired cookies (rows), but when somebody keeps creating new ones (by constantly logging in) they won't get deleted until some time, which gives the attacker a chance to spam the database. Updating cookies when IPs are the same would work, but then the idea of logging in from many devices could fail, because logging in from my computer would change the cookie that my phone (in same local network) created, therefore causing the phone to log-out

Comment: also adding a user-agent might work to identify your pc or mobile phone browsers... but iám not sure if the browser is sending a user-agent while in incognito mode or private mode.

Comment: A more advanced version off this method is SSL client certificates.. https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm  but it is much harder to implement might be a good reading.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with cookies hence thier expiration dates are set shorter for such purposes, You can also set the cookie values as encrypted message containing information of any session information or keys using a secret key which would solve all the problem